Work with JSON in BigQuery with dynamic keys
I have a json field in BigQuery called json_response. It has this shape:
{
    "2024-11-24": {
        "fatturato": {
            "numero": 281,
            "totale": 44444.72,
            "paesi": {
                "ITA": {
                    "num": 84,
                    "val": 33333.38
                },
                "USA": {
                    "num": 60,
                    "val": 20222.14
                }
            }
        },
        "ordini": {
            "totale": 5555.67,
            "num": 7,
            "paesi": {
                "ITA": {
                    "num": 14,
                    "val": 55.7
                },
                "USA": {
                    "num": 16,
                    "val": 222.5
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "2024-11-25": {
        "fatturato": {
            "numero": 225,
            "totale": 33333.72,
            "paesi": {
                "ITA": {
                    "num": 25,
                    "val": 22222.38
                },
                "USA": {
                    "num": 60,
                    "val": 20222.14
                }
            }
        },
        "ordini": {
            "totale": 5555.67,
            "num": 7,
            "paesi": {
                "ITA": {
                    "num": 14,
                    "val": 55.7
                },
                "USA": {
                    "num": 16,
                    "val": 222.5
                }
            }
        }
    },
}

I'd like to query it in order to have a column called ref_date (with the date in the keys, which can be many), a column "paesi", a column "fatturato_numero", "fatturato_valore" etcetera, ignoring the totals. In this case I'll have two rows, one for  "2024-11-24" and the other for " "2024-11-25"".
I tried using JSON_EXTRACT, but it says that keys must be constant, not dynamic.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use JSON_KEYS function to get all the keys from the JSON and then access theirs respective values:
SELECT 
    ref_date,
    json_column[ref_date].fatturato.paesi as paesi,
    json_column[ref_date].fatturato.numero as fatturato_numero
FROM sample, UNNEST(JSON_KEYS(sample.json_column, 1)) as ref_date

Output:

